# Summation of $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{T\left(n\right)}{n^{3}}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\phi\left(n\right)}{n^{3}}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Define $T(x)$ as $T(x) = \operatorname{gcd}(1,x)+\operatorname{gcd}(2,x)+ \dots+\operatorname{gcd}(x,x)$. How do I find the value of

$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{T\left(n\right)}{n^{3}}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\phi\left(n\right)}{n^{3}}}$$

where $\phi(x)$ is Euler's totient function?

Comment: Please edit for context and to show your efforts.  Do you have any reason to imagine that this will have a sensible solution?

Comment: Maybe the upper sum is a multiple of the bottom sum and can cancel out, but I don't know where to start in trying to get the upper sum in terms of the lower sum

Comment: Well, again.  What's the context?  Have you tried anything at all?  Can you compute numerator or denominator separately?  What do you get if you truncate the series at some repsectable level?

Comment: Dirichlet gives us a "closed form" for the denominator, in terms of values of $\zeta(s)$...maybe there's something similar for the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @lulu's comment on Dirichlet series:
$$DG(s,F):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}F(n)$$
Denominator is $DG(3,\varphi)$, for $T$
trivially (group by GCD):
$$T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \text{gcd}(n,i)=\sum_{d|n}d\varphi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$
Therefore, $T(n)$ is the convolution of $F(n)=n$ and $G(n)=\varphi(n)$

Hence the  Dirichlet series generating function is defined by
$$DG(3,T)=DG(3,n*\varphi)=DG(3,n)*DG(3,\varphi)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}DG(3,\varphi)$$
Hence the answer is $\zeta(2)$. Convergence etc. has to be checked but that should be left to the reader :)